# Use of malloc in c

Tags: c, malloc

We use malloc instead of arrays because we say that it blocks some space but even malloc does the same. it allocates required space and then frees it after. So what makes it special. And also how can we say it to be dynamic that is stored during programming as it also allocates those fixed no. of bytes as done by the array

Comment: "because we say that it blocks some space" Huh? What are you talking about?  "how can we say it to be dynamic that is stored during programming" What does that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

For array, we say it is static. because when we create it, it already allocates memory with given length. What makes special about dynamic allocation, sometimes, we do not know and do not want to allocate huge memory and make it wasted for doing nothing. In this case, dynamic allocation could have huge benefits over using array in terms of memory.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` allocated memory when the program is *running*. Hence it's dynamic.

The other kind of *static* form once initialization can't be changed and has an automatic storage lifetime i.e. it automatically gets de-allocated once out of the scope of the enclosing body.

Also, this kind of initialization `int arr[100]` allocates memory from the *stack*, whereas `malloc` calls allocate memory from the heap which is much more than the limited memory in stack (and sometimes a bit slower).